# How to write a curl in php to access some datas in php?

Tags: php

I have a curl code with me shown below :

```
curl --request GET \
--user 60CF3Ce97nRS1Z1Wp5m9kMmzHHEh8Rkuj31QCtVxjPWGYA9FymyqsK0Enm1P6mHJf0THbR:API-P4ss \
https://api.sandbox.ewaypayments.com/Transaction/44DD7aVwPYUPemGRf7pcWxyX2FJS-0Wk7xr9iE7Vatk_5vJimEbHveGSqX52B00QsBXqbLh9mGZxMHcjThQ_ITsCZ3JxKOY88WOVsFTLPrGtHRkK0E9ZDVh_Wz326QZlNlwx2
```

I wanted to write this code in a php file. I dnt know how to start writing this code. Can anyone tell how to write curl code in php ?

Comment: A good starting point would be the [PHP.net Documentation, covering CURL](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.curl.php)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$url = 'API URL';

try {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $APIresponse = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $res = json_decode($APIresponse, true);
    // $res contains the API response as an array
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
    // Error mesage
}
```

[Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.curl.php)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [PHP Client URL Library](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php).

Solution for your code:

```
<?php
$username = "60CF3Ce97nRS1Z1Wp5m9kMmzHHEh8Rkuj31QCtVxjPWGYA9FymyqsK0Enm1P6mHJf0THbR";
$password = "API-P4ss";
$process = curl_init("https://api.sandbox.ewaypayments.com/Transaction/44DD7aVwPYUPemGRf7pcWxyX2FJS-0Wk7xr9iE7Vatk_5vJimEbHveGSqX52B00QsBXqbLh9mGZxMHcjThQ_ITsCZ3JxKOY88WOVsFTLPrGtHRkK0E9ZDVh_Wz326QZlNlwx2");
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ":" . $password);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$return = curl_exec($process);
curl_close($process);
var_dump($return);
```

The response of API is in `$return` variable.

Comment: in the curl_init() which value is being added inside ?

Comment: @johanna It's an url to page.

Comment: is that url constant ?

Comment: the output is shown like this : string(66) "HTTP/1.1 400 BAD_REQUEST Content-Length: 0 Connection: Close "

Comment: Can anyone answer my question ?

Answer (score 0):

First use file_get_contents php function.

If your not found solution then try below code

```
//  Initiate curl
$ch = curl_init();
// Disable SSL verification
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
// Will return the response, if false it print the response
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
// Set the url
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
// Execute
$result=curl_exec($ch);
// Closing
curl_close($ch);

// Will dump a beauty json :3
var_dump(json_decode($result, true));
```